# Codeigniter Preg_match error

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, preg-match

I am trying to implement a search function that will use ajax to query the database when a user types a character into the search box This will bring up any data within the database that begins with the character typed by the user.

Comment: Which line is number 759?

Comment: @MikeofSST $_ci_ext = pathinfo($_ci_view, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: This looks very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9269473/3581917), even down to the line number.  Is it the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think this line, is your problem;

```
$this->load->view(array('words' => $wordlist));
```

You are trying to load an array of views.

The first parameter within the view function, is the name of the file you're trying to load. Like this;

```
$this->load->view('file_name', $data, true/false)
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: When i do this it loads a whole new view within the original view. Is there any way i can just display the array('words' => $wordlist) onto the same page?

Comment: In CodeIgniter there is no what's known directly as Layout. So, as work around, you have to divide your layout template into multiple views. for example, `$this->load->view('header');$this->load->view('body');$this->load->view('footer');`

Comment: From your question I bit that you want the wordlist to be rendred as AJAX output, so you can make an empty view file call it ajax.php with one variable encoded like the following: `echo ajax_encode($words);` and then in your controller `$this->load->view('ajax',array('words' => $wordlist));` @m93

Comment: @sємsєм I have done what you said but i now receive this error. Fatal error: Call to undefined function ajax_encode()

Comment: @m93 Sorry it is [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @sємsєм I ended up fixing my work, Thanks. I was wondering whether you also point out where i am going wrong in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556501/store-model-function-return-to-controller-function?noredirect=1#comment43539411_27556501

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific type of data and simple out, you must use header response without `$this->load->view` just like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('words' => $wordlist));
```

Use that, you can easily get data with ajax