# Store model function return to controller function

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

I have a model which returns a username of the person that has logged into the website to a controller. I am trying to save the username into a variable which i can user to then insert back into another table, however i am having no luck saving the data. Below is my model and controller classes.

Model:

```
function is_loggedin()
{
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
$res = $this->db->get_where('logins',array('session_id' => $session_id));

if ($res->num_rows() == 1) {
    $row = $res->row_array();
    return $row['name'];
}
else {
    return false;
}
}
```

Part of my Controller:

```
public function index()
{
$loggedin = $this->authlib->is_loggedin();

if ($loggedin === false) 
    $this->load->view('login_view',array('errmsg' => ''));
else
{

    $this->load->view('postquestion_view',array('username' => $loggedin));
    $user = $loggedin['username'];
}
}



   public function askquestion()
{

$qtitle = $this->input->post('title');
$qdetails = $this->input->post('details');
$qtags = $this->input->post('tags');
$qcategory = $this->input->post('category');
$quser = $user;
```

Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: user

Filename: controllers/postq.php

Line Number: 47
```

Comment: Please read your controller out loud and re-do question. (what if `$loggedin` is `FALSE`?)

Comment: @Kyslik That is how i originally had my code as (See edit). In the index function

Answer (score 0):

Here the error message is very clear. The variable `$user` in the last line of the function -action- `askquestion()` snippet is not defined. Basically, you have to read more about [**variables scope**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

In your current situation, the code of index action should be in [**constructor**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) and the variable `user` should be an object property. i.e it should defined globally in your controller's class and then takes its value from the constructor something like the following general demo:

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

       public $user = false;
       public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            // Your own constructor code
       }

       public function askquestion()
       {

              $qtitle = $this->input->post('title');
              $qdetails = $this->input->post('details');
              $qtags = $this->input->post('tags');
              $qcategory = $this->input->post('category');
              $quser = $this->user; //NOTICE THIS LINE
}
?>
```